# Lead assignment rules to Lead owner

Tags: leads, assignment-rules, web2lead

Please advise how to set Lead assignment rules where new leads that are manually being entered into the system by users form the Marketing department, remain as lead owner.
At the moment all Leads created either via web-to-lead or created manually are assigned to a queue.
 I would like to know how to set the manually created Leads being entered into the system by users form the Marketing department to be assigned to a lead owner.
 I do not want them to be assigned to a queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two ways to make the assignment robust.

First is user training thing. Whenever a lead is being created make sure user check the check box shown below:-

[image]

Case where Lead Assignment won't fire or does not satisfy business need:-

Second, you should have a Trigger on lead if lead assignment is little complex where you can change the owner during Lead creation.

If Lead is going to be assigned to a single user every time. User workflow of process builder instead of trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate Marketing department leads from other leads, for that you can use record types or custom field. 
if you are using record type then you condition can be:

```
Record Type = 'Web to Lead' then assign to Queue
```

I believe you are using lead assignment rule to assign leads to Queue, so based on your differentiation you need to give condition in assignment rule so that it can be assigned to only queue.
If lead does not match with the assignment rule criteria then it will automatically assigned to the user who created the record.